# The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null on firebase logout

Tags: flutter

Error is throwing when I try to logout using firebase. I tried this solution but it doesn't work for logout  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281488/unhandled-exception-nosuchmethoderror-the-method-findancestorstateoftype-was). Flutter Navigator is giving the error as mentioned in the link but that solution is not working.

```
E/flutter (17712): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'findAncestorStateOfType' was called on null.
E/flutter (17712): Receiver: null
E/flutter (17712): Tried calling: findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()
E/flutter (17712): #0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
E/flutter (17712): #1      Navigator.of 
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:2115
E/flutter (17712): #2      Navigator.pushReplacement 
package:flutter/…/widgets/navigator.dart:1781
E/flutter (17712): #3      _HandleMainScreenState.checkAuthentication.<anonymous closure> 
package:monktree/main.dart:55
E/flutter (17712): #4      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (17712): #5      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (17712): #6      _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (17712): #7      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (17712): #8      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:266:7)
E/flutter (17712): #9      _ForwardingStreamSubscription._add  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:134:11)
E/flutter (17712): #10     _MapStream._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:234:10)
E/flutter (17712): #11     _ForwardingStreamSubscription._handleData  (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:166:13)
E/flutter (17712): #12     _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1192:38)
E/flutter (17712): #13     _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1085:19)
E/flutter (17712): #14     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:987:7)
E/flutter (17712): #15     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
E/flutter (17712): #16     _DelayedData.perform  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:594:14)
E/flutter (17712): #17     _StreamImplEvents.handleNext  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:710:11)
E/flutter (17712): #18     _PendingEvents.schedule.<anonymous closure>  (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:670:7)
E/flutter (17712): #19     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1180:38)
```

When i try to logout using actions of the AppBar i get the above error. The code that i am using. There is an error in flutter navigator but i am unable to fix it.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  signout() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
      print(widget.user.uid);
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _logout() {
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                content: Text('Are you sure you want to logout'),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        signout();
                      },
                      child: Text('Yes')),
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Text('No'))
                ],
              ));
    }

    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      drawer: CustomDrawer(
        user: widget.user,
        userData: userdata,
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
          actions: <Widget>[
            Container(
                width: 200,
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  userdata['userName'],
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontSize: Constants.mediumText,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontFamily: 'Segoe'),
                )),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _logout();
              },
              child: Icon(
                Icons.exit_to_app,
                size: 30,
                color: Color(0xff747474),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          elevation: 1,
          leading: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return MaterialButton(
                child: drawericon,
                onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer());
          }),
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).canvasColor),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
signout() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut().then((value) {
      print(widget.user.uid);
      Navigator.pop(context);
  }
```

Changing your `signout()` to the above should make it. Then with a ternary expression you can check if the user token or `uid != null`.

For example:

```
home: auth.isAuth ? AuthScreen() : TabsScreen(),
```

Comment: when user log out i want to redirect to login screen. but i am using pushReplacement so Navigator.pop will not work. Please any other suggestions

Comment: I'm currently using it in my app it also has firebase authentification and it works perfectly using it in the provided way. you have to make sure you check it for example in the main.dart file. Oh btw also make sure your signout is async, also use await, possibly this could cause the issue you have. Youre welcome!